# Sum fields of an Inner join

Tags: sql

How I can add two fields that belong to an inner join?

I have this code:

```
  select

   SUM(ACT.NumberOfPlants ) AS NumberOfPlants,
   SUM(ACT.NumOfJornales) AS NumberOfJornals

   FROM dbo.AGRMastPlanPerformance MPR (NOLOCK)

   INNER JOIN GENRegion GR ON (GR.intGENRegionKey = MPR.intGENRegionLink )
   INNER JOIN AGRDetPlanPerformance DPR (NOLOCK) ON 
   (DPR.intAGRMastPlanPerformanceLink = 
   MPR.intAGRMastPlanPerformanceKey)
   INNER JOIN vwGENPredios P ​​(NOLOCK) ON ( DPR.intGENPredioLink = 
   P.intGENPredioKey )
   INNER JOIN AGRSubActivity SA (NOLOCK) ON (SA.intAGRSubActivityKey = 
   DPR.intAGRSubActivityLink)
   LEFT JOIN (SELECT RA.intGENPredioLink, AR.intAGRActividadLink, 
   AR.intAGRSubActividadLink, SUM(AR.decNoPlantas) AS 
   intPlantasTrabajads, SUM(AR.decNoPersonas) AS NumOfJornales,
   SUM(AR.decNoPlants) AS NumberOfPlants
   FROM AGRRecordActivity RA WITH (NOLOCK)

   INNER JOIN AGRActividadRealizada AR WITH (NOLOCK) ON 
   (AR.intAGRRegistroActividadLink = RA.intAGRRegistroActividadKey AND 
    AR.bitActivo = 1)
    INNER JOIN AGRSubActividad SA (NOLOCK) ON (SA.intAGRSubActividadKey 
   = AR.intAGRSubActividadLink AND SA.bitEnabled = 1)

    WHERE RA.bitActive = 1 AND
    AR.bitActive = 1 AND

    RA.intAGRTractorsCrewsLink IN(2)
    GROUP BY RA.intGENPredioLink,
     AR.decNoPersons,
     AR.decNoPlants,
     AR.intAGRAActivityLink,
     AR.intAGRSubActividadLink) ACT ON (ACT.intGENPredioLink IN( 
     DPR.intGENPredioLink) AND
     ACT.intAGRAActivityLink IN( DPR.intAGRAActivityLink) AND
     ACT.intAGRSubActivityLink IN( DPR.intAGRSubActivityLink))

     WHERE
     MPR.intAGRMastPlanPerformanceKey IN(4) AND
     DPR.intAGRSubActivityLink IN( 1153)

     GROUP BY
     P.vchRegion,
     ACT.NumberOfFloors,
     ACT.NumOfJournals
     ORDER BY ACT.NumberOfFloors DESC
```

However, it does not perform the complete sum. It only retrieves all the values ​​of the columns and adds them 1 by 1, instead of doing the complete sum of the whole column.

For example, the query returns these results:

[image]

What I expect is the final sums. In `NumberOfPlants` the result of the sum would be `163,237` and of `NumberJornales` would be `61`.

How can I do this?

Comment: Is this the entire query?

Comment: It's just an example of the query, which is actually something big but I have a problem with those two fields, do you think it can be clarified with this example oh I add the entire query

Comment: Then it's not enough of the full query, because it won't create the results shown in the question. I suspect the real query includes a `GROUP BY`, and we need to see that  and at least one of the other SELECT columns related to the GROUP BY, so we can put an answer in context. Also, you should read this: https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2023/02/07/what-you-need-to-know-about-nolock/

Comment: ready add the complete query I hope it is understandable
Thanks for the help

Comment: Okay, now we're at the other extreme. How about some middle ground? If you want help, do the work to find a minimal part of the query that can actually reproduce the issue.

Comment: Ok I will try to reduce it and show me the same result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all the `(nolock)` hints are probably **not** accomplishing the benefit you hope for. It's not an automatic "go faster" option, and if such an option existed you can be sure it would be already enabled. It can help in some situations, but the way it works allows the possibility of reading stale data, and the situations where it's likely to make any improvement are the same situations where risk for stale data is the highest.

That out of the way, with that much code in the question we're better served with a general explanation and solution for you to adapt.

The issue here is `GROUP BY`. When you use a `GROUP BY` in SQL, you're telling the database you want to see separate results *per group* for any aggregate functions like SUM() (and COUNT(), AVG(), MAX(), etc).

So if you have this:

```
SELECT Sum(ColumnB) As SumB
FROM [Table]
GROUP BY ColumnA
```

You **will** get a separate row per `ColumnA` group, even though it's not in the `SELECT` list.

If you don't really care about that, you can do one of two things:

1. **Remove the GROUP BY** If there are no grouped columns in the `SELECT` list, the `GROUP BY` clause is probably not accomplishing anything important.
2. **Nest the query**

If option 1 is somehow not possible (say, the original is actually a view) you could do this:

```
SELECT SUM(SumB)
FROM (
    SELECT Sum(ColumnB) As SumB
    FROM [Table]
    GROUP BY ColumnA
) t
```

Note in both cases any `JOIN` is irrelevant to the issue.

Comment: Thank you very much I was using functions that forced me to use Group by and separated the rows as you comment but it has already been resolved Thanks friend